# How to change a div to textarea and vice versa with only vanilla javascript without using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

how to change a div to a textarea to edit the text in the div when a button is clicked and the same button is clicked again then that textarea change to a div.

HTML

```
<button class="button">click me</button>
<div class="div">this is div or textarea</div>
```

JS

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const div = document.querySelector('div');


let isTextarea = false

button.addEventListener('click', () => { 
  if(isTextarea) {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    const textarea = document.createElement('textarea')
    div.innerHTML = textarea.value
    textarea.parentNode.replaceChild(div, textarea)
    isTextarea = false
  }else {
    const textarea =document.createElement('textarea')
    textarea.innerHTML = div.innerHTML
    div.parentNode.replaceChild(textarea, div)
    isTextarea = true
  }
} )
```

Comment: textarea has value, not innerHTML `textarea.innerHTML = div.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create both a `<div>` and a `<textarea>` in both branches. If you have a textarea, all you need to create is a div, and if you have a div, all you need to create is a textarea. (Referencing the `textarea.parentNode` of an element you just created and haven't appended anywhere throws an error, as expected - that doesn't make sense.)

You'll need to either select the existing `<div>` or `<textarea>` in the document

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
let isTextarea = false
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (isTextarea) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
    div.innerHTML = textarea.value;
    textarea.parentNode.replaceChild(div, textarea);
    isTextarea = false;
  } else {
    const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    const div = document.querySelector('div');
    textarea.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
    div.parentNode.replaceChild(textarea, div)
    isTextarea = true
  }
})
```

```html
<button class="button">click me</button>
<div class="div">this is div or textarea</div>
```

Or create both elements on pageload, but only append one initially.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const div = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
div.textContent = 'this is div or textarea';
const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');

let isTextarea = false
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (isTextarea) {
    div.innerHTML = textarea.value;
    textarea.parentNode.replaceChild(div, textarea);
    isTextarea = false;
  } else {
    textarea.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
    div.parentNode.replaceChild(textarea, div)
    isTextarea = true
  }
})
```

```html
<button class="button">click me</button>
```

You could also ditch the `isTextarea` flag if you wanted by checking which element [`.isConnected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/isConnected).

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const div = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
div.textContent = 'this is div or textarea';
const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (textarea.isConnected) {
    div.innerHTML = textarea.value;
    textarea.parentNode.replaceChild(div, textarea);
  } else {
    textarea.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
    div.parentNode.replaceChild(textarea, div)
  }
})
```

```html
<button class="button">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to replace the child unless there's some reason that the first child of the `.div` div must contain a particular thing.  Just hide whichever one you don't need.

```js
let div;
let textarea;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  div = document.querySelector('.div > div');
  textarea = document.querySelector('.div > textarea');

  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => { 
    div.classList.toggle('hidden')
    textarea.classList.toggle('hidden')
  } )

  textarea.addEventListener('input', () => { 
    div.innerHTML = textarea.value
  } )
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<button class="button">click me</button>
<div class="div"><div class="hidden"></div><textarea></textarea></div>
```